# UINavigationBar barButtonItem change back button image and title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to change the back button on a UINavigationBar and change the title?

When I try to set the customView property, I get an image right next to the default button.

I use this code

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backButtonImage landscapeImagePhone:nil style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

I want the title to be "Back" which is easy enough to do in Storyboard. But the problem is that no matter if I use code above or use customView property, the default back button remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `UIImage` to the `UIButton`. And, then use it as a custom back button. Here's a quick example:

```
// Custom image
UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-background-image.png"];
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[backButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
[backButton setBackgroundImage:backButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// Custom title
[backButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(barPayButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:NO];

UIBarButtonItem *buttonOnBar =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonOnBar;
```

**Note:** You will loose the chevron (system-provided back arrow) which was introduced in iOS7. It goes as a title and chevron together presenting your previous view controller.

**Update:**

You can also use `UIEdgeInsets` to resize your image intelligently.

```
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 15, 10); 
UIImage *backButtonImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"button-background-image.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsets];
```

Comment: Do I need to add the "Back" title to the image to display it or is there a way to set it separately from the button/image combo?

Comment: @noobsmcgoobs Updated with the combo. Its bit tricky - you have to be very cautious with the background image coordinates. I have hardcoded it (100,30). Once you get it right - do self.view.frame.size.width (or height) to fit title inside it.

Comment: Yeah, it stretches out the image to add the text. I'm just going to change the button frame and add the text to the image. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Funny thing: I spent whole day today in retaining the 'chevron' arrow we loose by doing this (adding custom image/title) - I failed. Glad I was able to help you.

Comment: It's either or it seems. I don't think the framework offers that level of flexibility. If you dig deep enough into the underlying struct of that object, it's probably possible to do so, though too much of a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by setting the `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` of the view controller that's being pushed to the custom bar button item with the look you want. Good Luck!